# Payment subscription using PayPal and Django

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want a user to be able to pay with credit card or debit card using Django and PayPal, because **stripe** is not working in Nigeria.

Comment: In your profile it said that you are from nigeria ,is there `orange money` in your country ?

Comment: In Nigeria there is a `JumiaPay` if your users are from nigeria then i think it will be easier to see if they have some api to make payements with.I am from russia they block the access from russian users here is what they said `You do not have access to pay.jumia.ma.

The site owner may have set restrictions that prevent you from accessing the site. Contact the site owner for access or try loading the page again.`(https://pay.jumia.ma/)  so make your own search i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [www.paypal.com/worldwide](https://www.paypal.com/worldwide) -> Nigeria, you can see that Business accounts are not supported for the country. Only personal accounts, for making payments. The receiving account must be outside Nigeria.

For countries that **do** support PayPal business accounts to receive payments, [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) can be integrated. With such an integration, payers **may** have the ability to pay as a guest without creating an account, which can look something like the following

[image]

Comment: So that's means I shouldn't use PayPal for my Django project if my Customer are in Nigeria ?

Comment: The account receiving the payments cannot be in Nigeria.